# SilverStripe single one-to-one objects bug

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a one-to-one relation between `Team` and `Coach`. I use [has one edit module](https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit/blob/master/README.md) to edit the Coach's name directly via the `Team` gridfield edit page.

On the first `Team` save, two `Coach` records are created with the supplied names. However **on each consecutive save a new `Coach` record is created**, which is obviously not the desired outcome. Instead, it should save the updated names to the same records, because the coaches don't change, it's just their columns (names) that change.

**Team**

```
class Team extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one {
        'MainCoach' => 'Coach',
        'AssistentCoach' => 'Coach'
    );
}
```

**Coach**

```
class Coach extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar'
    );
```

**Team edit page**

```
public function getCMSFields() {

    TextField::create('MainCoach-_1_-Name', 'Main coach name'),      // main coach name
    TextField::create('AssistentCoach-_1_-Name', 'Assistent coach name')  // assistent coach name

}
```

Comment: If you think this is a bug of the module in question, you should report it as a bug on their issue-tracker. Btw. both your field names are identical… I guess you'd want the second one to read `AssistentCoach-_1_-Name` ?

Comment: @bummzack it's reported to the mod issue tracker on github indeed. And yes, the name issue was a type error

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/relations/#polymorphic-has-one see http://www.balbuss.com/multiple-has-manys-of-the-same-class/ < should be valid still

Comment: seems it's an error, cause you have two has-one relations to coach and it doesn't know what to use?

Comment: might also be possible you need a relation back to to Team, this would be using `$belongs_to`, see http://silverstrip.es/blog/diagram-of-relationships-in-silverstripe/

Comment: @wmk I've narrowed the issue down and indeed the bug only persists when **two relations with the same class type** are set. Even though this is a perfectly valid silverstripe object relation as Finbowa said. Issue is raised here: https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit/issues/5 . Also, the `$belongs_to` back doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: reading the module's code i cannot find right now where the objects are created. Do you have some other magic in your code (e.g. in onBeforeWrite()...)? With xdebug it should be easy to see what's going on there...

Comment: does the github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit/ support on using the dot syntax if it doesnt a quick hot fix could be just to add a new class that just extends the original wihtout adding new db fielts. Just remember to add the belongs_to or has_many to the other end to make the relation complete. Eg if you can't "name" it with the dot notation use an additional class.

Comment: @FinBoWa That's actually a great idea. Assuming `Foo has_one `Bar` I just tested the case with 2 new classes with unique names that both extend `Bar`. Unfortunately the bug still occurs. The mod keeps creating new records

Comment: More info here: https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit/issues/5